# bash function sourced from .bashrc does not cd to folder

Tags: linux, bash, awk

[image: doesn't cd from bash script]

The if..else block in the install_gawk doesn't work while it works perfectly well in install_sed function which are same. In fact I've reused (copy pasted) my install_sed function to create install_gawk function.
I'm posting here after trying out quite a few things. Below are my both the functions.

```
install_sed() {

    echo "Paste path to latest 'sed source file' from here: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/sed/ e.g., sed-4.2.2.tar.bz2" ;
    read sedlink ;

    wget -c $sedlink ;

    tar xvf sed-* ;

    sleep 5;

   if [ -d sed-* ] ; then

       cd sed-* ;

   else

       echo "no sed-* folder to cd.." ;

   fi

    ./configure ;

    make ;

    make check ;

    sudo make install ;

    sed --version ;

}


# if..else block should cd to gawk-* folder like it did in the sed folder but it doesn't cd.


install_gawk() {

 echo " download latest awk from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/ e.g.,  gawk-4.1.1.tar.xz "
 read gawklink ;

 wget -c $gawklink;

 tar xvf gawk-* ;

 sleep 5;

   if [ -d gaw-* ] ; then

        cd gaw-* ;

    else

        echo "no gawk-* folder to cd.." ;

    fi


    ./configure ;

    make ;

    make check ;

    sudo make install ;

    gawk --version ;

}
```

Comment: P.S. Just to make clear that the gawk-4.2.0 folder is present in the home directory..

Comment: You have omitted all error checking. Maybe your first step is to add error checking, and then run your script through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). You might also want to visit [Noloader | Build Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts).

Comment: @jww I did use 'exit' in if..else block. Just edited the scrip before posting here. I thought it must not be relevant to my question, so. https://imgur.com/a/5gTRq

Comment: I think you need to provide the actual script you are using, and stop posting those pictures all over the web. Copy and paste your error text with the question.

Comment: `install_gawk() {

 echo " download latest awk from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gawk/ e.g.,  gawk-4.1.1.tar.xz "
 read gawklink ;
 
 wget -c $gawklink;
 
 tar xvf gawk-* ;

 sleep 5;

   if [ -d gawk-* ] ; then
        
        cd gawk-* ;
    
    else

        echo "no gawk-* folder to cd.." ;
        exit;

    fi

    ./configure ;

    make ;
    
    make check ;

    sudo make install ;
    
    gawk --version ;

}
 `     **Error in bash is - bash: [: gawk-4.2.0: binary operator expected
no gawk folder**

Comment: Why a negative. For asking a question ? I don't understand.

Comment: @jww Thankyou. I checked my script with shellcheck as you suggested, and found the solution here. (https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2144). I used a for loop instead of if..else.  
` for gawk in /home/directory/*;
 do
     if [ -d "$gawk" ] ; then 
         cd gawk*;
         break
     fi
 done

`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have typo in directory name pattern in if-else condition for *gawk*

> if [ -d gaw-* ] ; then
>
> ```
>    cd gaw-* ;
> ```
>
> else

Which should be like -

```
   ...
   if [ -d gawk-* ] ; then

        cd gawk-* ;

   else
   ..
```